# How to prevent buttons from submitting forms when value is not selected. Without using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, button

Is there anyway of preventing buttons from submitting forms when the value is not selected, without using javascript?

Here is my code.

```
<!-- form -->
<form name="aform" action="second_page.php" method="POST">
    <div id="collegelane">
         Please choose only one from the following rooms:
    </div>

    <?php

         // connects to database
         require("user_connection.php");


         $q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus`");
         while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
         echo '<input id="onclick" type="checkbox" name="car" 
            value="'.$line['room'].'"><label>'.$line['room'].'</label></br>';
        }

    ?>

    </br>
    </br>

    <div id="next">
        <input type="submit" name="next" Value="next"/>
    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/exposing-form-fields-radio-button-css/ - make the submit button invisible unless checkbutton checked

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `required` attribute can be used for checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

as it has already been suggested add a 'required' attribute on your checkbox as follows, it should work. Not sure about browser support for that attribute, i suspect it might not work on some version of IE.

```
<?php

             // connects to database
             require("user_connection.php");


             $q = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `campus`");
             while ($line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)) {
             echo '<input id="onclick" required type="checkbox" name="car" 
                value="'.$line['room'].'"><label>'.$line['room'].'</label></br>';
            }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

html5 form validation:
http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

AngularJs  form validation:
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms